# C# - comparing values in 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple. The user inputs a string. The program checks and counts the number of vowels present in that text string.

```
    char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    int counter = 0;

    string s = txtInput.Text.Trim();
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();


    foreach (char i in arr)
    {
        //checks the 2 arrays for matches
        counter++;
    }
```

How can I check the 2 arrays to see if there are any matches?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array.IndexOf()` for this:

```
if (Array.IndexOf(vowels, i) >= 0)
{
    // the character is present
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
arr.Any(p => vowels.Contains(p));
```

Update: 
To calculate number of matches you may use;

```
 int count = arr.Where(p => vowels.Contains(p)).Count();
```

Comment: In the question count is not asked, but you may find using int count = arr.Where(p => vowels.Contains(p)).Count();

Comment: The question asks for count: **The program checks and counts the number of vowels**

Answer (score 2):

Simply use two `foreach` loops

```
foreach(var i in arr)
    {
        foreach(var j in vowels)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use LINQ:

```
arr.Select(c => vowels.Contains(c));
```

In order to get the count of characters you can use `Count` method instead of `Select`.
If you want to just know if there are any vowels, then use `Any` - it will terminate as soon as it founds the first match.

Comment: I have no knowledge in LINQ as of now since I'm merely in the beginner stage if learning C#. But thanks for that information. I'll keep that in mind. It seems easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if (vowels.Contains(i))
 {
    counter++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create a list of characters for vowels, and then use the [.contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ for that!

```
bool anyMatches = arr.Intersect(vowels).Any();
```

or, if you want the matches:

```
var matches = arr.Intersect(vowels).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

or to count the exact number of matches:

```
int count = arr.Count(x => vowels.Contains(x));
```

Comment: This counts the number of different vowels, not the total number of vowels ("woot" produces one 'o')

Comment: Yes, look at the presented code - for each character in arr he wants to check the other array for matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Linq Query

```
var q=from c in s 
  where vowels.Contains(c)
  group c by c into g
  select  new {vowel=g.Key, count=g.Count()};
```

then you can iterate and do what you like with the contents

e.g.

```
 foreach (var x in q) {
     Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} : {1}",x.vowel,x;count));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash<char> vowels = //initialize to vowels.

foreach(char c in input)
{
   if(hashset(vowels) contains the character)
      increment counter.
}

return counter.
```